# Unbale to upload media to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to upload media to my wordpress site. I'm Getting error message :

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

I'm using the wp-crowdfunding plugin.

When a user signs up to it.. it is registered as a subscriber (role) and when im trying to upload using an admin account it is working properly.

But when subscriber is uploading thru it's account then im getting error.

After error if i click logout it will redirect me to a page of abrupt log out saying something went wrong.....

Any help would be appriciated

here is the url of website: funded247.com/login

try to sign up and then upload media using loing>> start a campaign >> add media>> upload ... u will get same error..

Comment: The Subscriber role doesn't have the `upload_files` permission which is most likely the reason why this is happening (see [Capability vs Role table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table)). You'll either need to change the default role to Author, or create a custom role with the `upload_files` capability included. (Also, this kind of question is probably best asked at [WP Crowdfunding's Support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-crowdfunding/).)

Comment: that's the problem.... subscriber has the upload_files permission .... i checked

Comment: Then please go to the plugin's support forum and ask there. It might be a bug in the plugin, the developer should be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: they hardly help ...

Comment: Their support forum seems pretty active to me, though. Anyways, do what you feel its best for you. Good luck!